# Replication in sql server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2019

I am reading 'Pro SQL Server 2019 Administration' book from Carter, and when detailing HA and DR options, 'replication' is not mentioned:

[image]

Why is it omited? Will Replication be deprecated soon?

Answer (score 8):

> Why is it omitted?

Because the replication NOT considered to be HA and DR solution, it is considered to be **[Migrate & Load Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)** feature within SQL Server, which mainly cover the requirement of distributing subset of data into different locations wherein HA and DR solution mainly focuses on whole database/SQL-Instance level Failover capabilities.

> Will Replication be deprecated soon?

I don't think whole replication feature will be depreciated, perhaps some sub-features of replication. [for your reference..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/deprecated-features-in-sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Mirroring looks like replication to me (all DB changes are replicated from one instance to another), and mirroring is the heart of Availability Groups.

Answer (score 3):

Another angle is that the other technologies gives you a binary copy of the database.

Replication doesn't. It scripts out your stuff, uses DDL to create the objects and sniffs the modification and generates INS/UPD/DEL based on that. Unless both you and the replication software does it perfectly right, you will miss stuff in the "replica" database. Something you might not feel to happy about in a failover situation.